Generate two key pairs and testing them for equality says they aren't equal. Why?
To generate these keys, I xor two values together. The methods that perform this operation yield the keySeed value. This operation was considered trivial and hence it isn't disclosed in the code that I have quoted.
Using SHA1 keys, I go about calculating the key pair twice. I then compare the first key pair to the second and see if I get a true or a false answer.
I have tried a comparison using mock-up code, and I have disclosed the main method here. The code generates what I believed would be the same key pair twice and compares them...
        var arg1="65cfa78989387ca19f18d1d54af0d45dfb8fd9ee";
        var arg2="783C82C2E6394A329A8149564E1B6AB74AA70FBD";
        var keySeed=Sovereignty.bitwiseXor(Sovereignty.hexStringToByteArray(arg1),Sovereignty.hexStringToByteArray(arg2));

        SecureRandom random;
        try{
            random=SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException x){
            throw new RuntimeException(x);
        }

        // First key...
        
        random.setSeed(keySeed);

        KeyPairGenerator keyGen1;
        try{
            keyGen1=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException x){
            throw new RuntimeException(x);
        }

        keyGen1.initialize(1024,random);
        
        var firstKey=keyGen1.generateKeyPair();

        // Second key...
        
        random.setSeed(keySeed);

        KeyPairGenerator keyGen2;
        try{
            keyGen2=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException x){
            throw new RuntimeException(x);
        }

        keyGen2.initialize(1024,random);
        
        var secondKey=keyGen2.generateKeyPair();
        
        System.out.println(firstKey.getPublic().equals(secondKey.getPublic()));

However, the test on the final line returns false, when I am expecting it to return true.
What am I doing wrong?

What is Sovereignty?

Maybe that key class doesn't implement equals. Hard to say as you don't show which classes these are (no [mcve]). But more importantly... why do you want to compare these keys? What are you trying to do? This sounds a lot like an xy problem.

I agree with Robert. This is definitely an "XY Problem." The key problem seems to be your understanding of how the contract for the equals() method works. Since the object types are unknown to us, as Robert pointed out, it is likely that whatever type is being returned by getPublic() method does not override Object's equals method. Therefore, the only thing the method is doing comparing the object references; which clearly are not equal. What you are trying to do (unsuccessfully) is comparing the internal values of these objects. Of course, this is speculation for the reasons mentioned.

Also, you MUST include reproducible code. This includes import statements so that people who are trying to help will know what libraries to import in order to attempt to reproduce the issue. By obfuscating these important pieces of information, you are making it extremely difficult for people to provide adequate help; which will result in your question to be downvoted and closed due to lack of clarity. If you really want people to help you, provide complete and reproducible code.

subsequent SecureRandom.setSeed does not entirely replace the seed (unlike plain-Random, which does) so you need a new SecureRandom.getInstance . PS: I hope you know DSA-1024 has been obsolete for a decade. @Robert+ sun.security.provider.DSAPublicKey[Impl] subclasses sun.security.x509.X509Key which does implement equals() and hashCode().

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks, using a new SecureRandom instance works, although I am intrigued to know why this is the case. I know that SHA1 has long been rendered obsolete. Replacing SHA1 with a better algorithm will be a bridge to cross at a later time. Thanks.

@NguyenManhCuong It doesn't matter.

SecureRandom.setSeed(byte[]) does not what you seem to expect.
The documentation clearly states that

The seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed. Thus, repeated calls are guaranteed never to reduce randomness.

That means that after calling setSeed() with the same byte sequence you do not get the same sequence of random bytes but your code seems to expect that the random generator will generate the same sequence of random bytes.

Thanks for pointing that out to me. Indeed, I was expecting the same sequence of random bytes after calling setSeed with the same sequence. If I can't do it through setSeed, then how else should I do it? What Dave Thompson said in a comment to my question is helpful.
